# Not getting Execute Code First Migration according to publishprofilesetting

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ef-code-first

I am getting strange behavior while publishing(Web Deploy) MVC project with Code First Migration.
Publish File code is :

```
 <PublishDatabaseSettings>
      <Objects xmlns="">
        <ObjectGroup Name="DefaultConnection" Order="1" Enabled="True">
          <Destination Path="Data Source=abc.def.com;Initial Catalog=TestDB;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=user;Password=is123" />
          <Object Type="DbCodeFirst">
            <Source Path="DBMigration" DbContext="isMVC.Models.ApplicationDbContext, isMVC" MigrationConfiguration="isMVC.Migrations.Configuration, isMVC" Origin="Configuration" />
          </Object>
        </ObjectGroup>
      </Objects>
    </PublishDatabaseSettings>
```

But I get "Update-Database" as an option :
[image]

Since the Object Type is "DbCodeFirst", so it should be "Execute Code First Migration" option while web deploy.

Any help please!
Thanks in advance.